# jQuery call not working after Isotope filter is implemented

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-isotope

I'm currently using the isotope plugin for a fluid layout, I can successfully filter the content, but after the filters have been called, the rest of my jQuery calls fail to work.
Bear with me, I'm still new to jQuery but here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".pics-hidden").hide();


jQuery('.pics').click(function() {
      jQuery('#div'+jQuery(this).attr('rarget')).addClass('pics').removeClass('pics-hidden').delay(300).fadeIn(100);
      jQuery('#projectimages').isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
      return false;
       });       

var $container = $('#projectimages');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.pics',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 4
    }
});


$('#menu a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
});
```

The filter works fine, as does the ('pics') click function, BUT after the filter has been called, the ('.pics') click function now fails to work.
Is there a reason for this? Or a way to solve it? Tried all sorts, nothing seems to be working.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `jQuery('.pics').click(function() {` with

```
jQuery('#projectimages').on("click", ".pics", function() {
```

does it work any better? This way when you add the `pics` class to elements they should trigger your click handler.

Alternatively, could you provide a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: no, that's not worked unfortunately. I have a demo uploaded onto my server here: http://www.nealfletcher.co.uk/testing-testing/testin Clicking on the orange box in the top left will successfully show the corresponding div, but after 'Filter 1' has been called, this click function no longer works?

Comment: is there no way of me being able to show those divs after the filter has occurred then?

Comment: You could reverse the styles that isotope applies to them, or you can ensure that any divs which should appear after a click include an appropriate class.